# retrieve a row of data from documentum via DQL

Tags: javafx, dql, documentum

I have a list of users in my list view which is populated by retrieving data from documentum . If I click on any row of this least (each row represent one user) I should be able to see all of their information listed down .(**This is my problem** )

```
public void selectedItemFromListView(){
     selected = lwAllUserGrp.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
     System.out.println(selected);
     String query =" select * from dm_user where user_name = '@aclName'" ;
     String test = query.replace("@aclname", selected);

     GetDataWithDqlProfile(_session , query , "user_login_name" , "user_address" , "user_state" );
     System.out.println(user.getAddress());
     System.out.println(user.getState());
     System.out.println(user.getUsername());

}
```

if I click on a row of list view I can successfully see who is selected and I need to retrieve all the other attributes of that username (same person) from documentum via DQL .

```
private void GetDataWithDqlProfile(IDfSession session, String Query, String username , String address , String state ) {

    try {
        IDfQuery UpdateQuery = new DfQuery();
        UpdateQuery.setDQL(Query);
        IDfCollection col = UpdateQuery.execute(_session, IDfQuery.DF_QUERY);


            user.setAddress(col.getString(username));
            user.setUsername(col.getString(address));
            user.setState(col.getString(state));

        col.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, e.getMessage());
        alert.showAndWait();
        Logs.WriteLog(LoginController.Repository + ",User:" + LoginController.Username, "DQL Query", e.toString());
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
```

and my output is :

```
User's name 
null
null 
null
```

*I've tried the DQL query in DQL tester and it works well*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you referring to this question later here is how I solved the problem :

```
public ArrayList<User> GetDataWithDqlpro(IDfSession session, String Query, String username , String state , String address) {

    try {
        IDfQuery UpdateQuery = new DfQuery();
        UpdateQuery.setDQL(Query);
        IDfCollection col = UpdateQuery.execute(_session, IDfQuery.DF_QUERY);

        while (col.next()) {
            list.add( new User(col.getString(username),col.getString(address) , col.getString(state)));

        }
        col.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            alert.showAndWait();
            Logs.WriteLog(LoginController.Repository + ",User:" + LoginController.Username, "DQL Query", e.toString());
            e.getStackTrace();
}
        return (ArrayList<User>) list;

}



public void selectedItemFromListView(){
     selected = lwAllUserGrp.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
     System.out.println(selected);
     String Query = "select user_login_name , user_state , user_address from dm_user where user_login_name ='@aclname'";
     Query = Query.replace("@aclname",selected );
     ArrayList<User> allUserNames = GetDataWithDqlpro(_session, Query, "user_login_name","user_address","user_state");
     for (int i = 0 ; i <= allUserNames.size()-1 ; i++ ){
         if (selected.compareToIgnoreCase(allUserNames.get(i).getUsername() ) == 0){
                System.out.println(allUserNames.get(i).getState() );
                System.out.println(allUserNames.get(i).getAddress() );
                System.out.println(allUserNames.get(i).getUsername() );

         }

     }
```

}

Worth mentioning that I have a class called User with constructor and get and set methods

*I hope it will help some one :)*

Answer (score 2):

In order to fetch rows from IDfCollection you have to call `next()` on the collection object. This method both advances to the next row and returns a boolean if successful. Use a boolean test (e.g., `while` or `if`) to iterate, like this:

```
IDfCollection col = UpdateQuery.execute(_session, IDfQuery.DF_QUERY);

if (col.next()) {
    user.setAddress(col.getString(username));
    user.setUsername(col.getString(address));
    user.setState(col.getString(state));
}

col.close();
```

The iteration is necessary even if the collection contains only one row. In other words, you need to manually advance to the first row.

Comment: The error is gone but I still get null for all 3 of them ;)  @eivamu

Comment: Try adding some debug output inside the `if(){}` block, to see if `next()` returns `true`. If that's not the case, your DQL is wrong or just simply returns an empty collection (no rows).

Answer (score 2):

1) As @eiviamu already mentioned, you have to call IDfCollection.next() to get the next row.
2) Your code, among other problems, has one documentum-related: closing of collection must happen **always** in `finally` block.
Otherwise you can get unclosed collection which might lead to memory leaks and weird application behavior (e.g. if I'm not mistaken there are 9 simultaneous open collections are allowed for one DCTM session by default, and if you exceed this limit an exception will be thrown)